# .forEach() Javascript function is returning an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-6

Generally, It is said that 'forEach' doesn't return an array, whereas 'map' returns one. However, In my case, it is returning one. Below posted is my code. I am kind of confused. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Code Snippet //
var arr = [1, 3, 2];
var arr_temp = [];

arr.forEach(function (i) {
  return arr_temp.push(i + i);
});

console.log(arr_temp);
```

I am getting the output as:
[2,6,4]

Comment: it doesn't return anything, you are simply modifying array inside it

Comment: You are pushing into `arr_temp` and then `console.log(arr_temp)` it. The `return` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: this code describes the output you're getting by pushing those values to your temp array. What is the expected output?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't care about returned values.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of `forEach`. Do `var result = arr.forEach(...);` and inspect `result`. It will be `undefined`, not an array. Obviously `arr_temp` is an array, since you do `var arr_temp = [];`.

Comment: If you did this properly, it would be `var arr_temp = arr.map(i => i + i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't return anything. You can check that by logging the result of the `forEach` call:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 2];
var arr_temp = [];

console.log(arr.forEach(function (i) {
  return arr_temp.push(i + i);
})); // undefined

console.log(arr_temp); // 2, 6, 4
```

Comment: @Gothodo But it is returning the updated values in the arr_temp  right??

Comment: @mohanbabu No. It simply modifies the `arr_temp` array.

Comment: @mohanbabu: No. It does not *return* anything. **You** are adding values to `arr_temp` by doing `arr_temp.push(i + i)`. That line literally means "add `i +i` to the array referenced by `arr_temp`".